# Seeding a 1-to-1 relationship with Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I may be doing this wrong, but that's why I'm here. To get some experience with MVC I have created an MVC 4 application to build a kind of Personal Portfolio with. As part of my Entity Framework 5 set-up, I'm envisioning every 1 `[Project]` having 1 `[Contract]`, and every 1 `[Project]` having 1 `[ProjectType]`.

So for my Models I have set-up the following:

**Projects Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace PersonalPortfolio.Models
{
    public class Projects
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CompletedDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProjectTypesId")]
        public virtual ProjectTypes ProjectType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ContractId")]
        public virtual Contracts ContractId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Contracts Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PersonalPortfolio.Models
{
    public class Contracts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ContractLocationSrc { get; set; }
        public Boolean Signed { get; set; }


        public virtual string ContractLocationUrl
        {
            get
            {
                //TODO:update the folder when it isn't null to the blob storage location
                if (this.ContractLocationSrc == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "/Content/Contracts/" + this.ContractLocationSrc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ProjectTypes Model** - I see this as kind of a LookUp table?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PersonalPortfolio.Models
{
    public class ProjectTypes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After creating my `Models` I then set-up my `DbContext` in a `~/DAL/PortfoliContext.cs` file as shown by http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application under the **Create the Database Context** section.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using PersonalPortfolio.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace PersonalPortfolio.DAL
{
    public class PortfolioContext : DbContext
    {
        public PortfolioContext()
            : base("PortfolioContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Visitors> Visitors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VisitorPrivileges> VisitorPrivileges { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Privileges> Privileges { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProjectTypes> ProjectTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contracts> Contracts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Invoices> Invoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Receipts> Receipts { get; set; }

        // Allows/Disallows Tables to be Pluralized when created.
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    } 
}
```

Then in my **Configuration.cs** under my `~/Migrations/` folder, I have:

```
namespace PersonalPortfolio.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using PersonalPortfolio.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PersonalPortfolio.DAL.PortfolioContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(PersonalPortfolio.DAL.PortfolioContext context)
        {
            #region Projects
            try
            {
                var projects = new List<Projects>
                {
                    new Projects
                    {
                        ProjectName = "Chuck Finley's Boats",
                        ProjectType = 2,                       
                        StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-07-17"),
                        CompletedDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-03-08"),
                        ContractId = 2
                    }
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error Seeding Projects: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

### The Issue:

When I am seeding my Projects, the below for `ProjectType = 2` yields `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'PersonalPortfolio.Models.Contracts`, and then `ContractId = 2` likewise yields `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'PersonalPortfolio.Models.ProjectTypes'`.

```
var projects = new List<Projects>
                {
                    new Projects
                    {
                        ProjectName = "Chuck Finley's Boats",
                        ProjectType = 2,                       
                        StartDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-07-17"),
                        CompletedDate = DateTime.Parse("2012-03-08"),
                        ContractId = 2
                    }
                };
```

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong logically in trying to set/seed this relationship for a Project and it's Contract & ProjectType?

### EDIT:

When doing as [markpsmith] suggested and trying to add the `InitialMigration` to view how the Framework Creates the relationships within the database, I went into the `Package Manager Console` and typed command `add-migration InitialCreate`, which then errored out with the following: `The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.`

My `~/Web.config` file is the following, with only 1 warning for  the `<providers>` tag (5th from bottom) which says `The element 'entityFramework' has invlaid child element 'providers'. List of possible elements expected: 'contexts'`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PortfolioContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=PortfolioDevDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\PortfolioDevDatabase.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="PersonalPortfolio" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
        <add namespace="PagedList.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you already create the Tables in the DB? It bugs me the way your create your models definition.

Comment: Not yet, I've only set up the Models and I'm working on the initial seeding. If you have better suggestions for the Model definitions I'm open to ideas, completely new to MVC development.

Comment: ProjectType and ContractId are probably referring to Types, rather than the Foreign Key int, which might be called ProjectType_Id or similar.  Can you create your initialization without seeding any data?  That will create your tables & you'll be able to see what EF names the FK as? I'm assuming this is Code First btw.

Comment: Build the whole type and then associate that instead of trying to associate by the key.  Just read what the error says.

Comment: Specifically, you've said you want a Contracts object, but then you're trying to assign an int, and the compiler is complaining that it doesn't know of any way to turn an int into a Contracts object.  The FK handling has to happen behind the scenes.  You don't need to explicitly assign keys at all.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic as the other guys said, you should redefined your models, then create the DB and then seed it.

Comment: @markpsmith, Yes, this is supposed to be Code First. I have tried doing the Initial Migration as you suggested to create the database, but am receiving an error as detailed in my EDIT above. To Guillelon, As for redefining the model, I'm not sure I understand what need redefining?

Comment: does your project have a reference to EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll?

Comment: @markpsmith, under `~/PersonalPortfolio/References/` I have  EntityFramework listed, but not sure I have or know how to check if I have one for `EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`?

Comment: I think you should have both

Comment: fwiw, when I've done this I named my virtual properties as you have done, but I also explicitly name a FK property in the model, which for ProjectType would be ProjectTypeId.  EF seems to be happy with this & it gives me control over the naming convention.  As a side note, your title says EF5, but your web.config says EF6

Comment: @markpsmith, thanks! It took some work, but I finally got the initial migration to go through. I also think I had my foreign keys backwards, and should have for instance had Contracts with a foreign key to ProjectsID (since all contracts will be linked to a project). Now I seem to have an issue with my seed method for Privileges (which is also the first of my "Tables" that I attempt to seed): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385151/error-seeding-database-mvc-4-application-ef-5-code-first